# Error on page creation using Tridion UI

Tags: 2011, experience-manager

I have run into a little problem with the SiteEdit/UI/Experience Manager. I have upgraded from 2009 to 2011 SP1 and the majority of things seem to work fine except I'm getting an error every time I create a page. The problem occurs when it tries to create the page and it fails with the error message shown below. Despite failing it does succeed in creating the actual page and if I reload the page with the error message everything appears fine.

The implementation is done with VBScript and I have tried to apply this UI_2012.0.0.81248 hotfix, but it didn't solve the problem. I do have a blank page in the root of my website, so it shouldn't be related to the 404 error which sometimes happen with the UI.

```
Compiler Error Message: CS1576: The line number specified for #line directive is missing or invalid

Line 138:    #line hidden
Line 139:    
Line 140:    #line 0 "D:\Websites\[my website]\en\products-solutions\dfsdf.aspx"
Line 141:    using ASP;
```

Comment: I'd probably raise a ticket with SDL Tridion support for this one. - good luck

Comment: Thank you for your comment, John. I have already raised this with SDL Tridion support and they are looking into it as well.

Comment: @RuneV did you get any response/solution, would be worth posting it here as an answer and accepting that, so it can be used for future reference by others who might encounter the same issue?

Comment: @BartKoopman unfortunately SDL Tridion support is still looking into this one.

Comment: Not sure if `#line hidden` is actually in your code, but looking up the the [CS1576 Compiler Error](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwd3et10(v=vs.90).aspx) suggests this is missing a line number. Maybe try removing line 138 or adding a number there?

Comment: @AlvinReyes Thank you, Alvin. I will try give it a go.

Comment: Hi Rune V - Did you get an answer to this yet? Perhaps you could answer your own question?

Comment: @johnwinter, unfortunately, I have had to put this one on a temporarily hold. I have yet to find a solution for this but will share it once I find one.

Comment: What does your OData log show when this error happens?

Comment: Rune - was this ever resolved? did the comments from Mr Sizer below shed any light? did SDL Support get back to you?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is there anything on either of these pages that can provide enlightenment:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/34dk387t(v=vs.90).aspx

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13192690/tridion-ui-2012-error-the-item-tcm280-29837-64-does-not-exist

The compiler error implies that the error is on line 138.  Have you tried deleting that line and manually re-keying it?  If any of the code was copy/pasted, could differing original encoding have introduced a rogue character that looks right to us but the compiler doesn't recognise?

Line 140 suggests that the compiler treats the line as line zero.  Does the compiler line numbering actually go down to zero or start at one?

Finally, is it possible that during your upgrade process a file was missed and the error being reported is not actually the real error at all?

Like in Visual Studio when a PDB is out-of-sync with the executing code and you're stepping through with the debugger, pulling your hair out trying to understand why your code is acting illogical.